# Golang Trigger Cloud Function via http

Tags: function, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I try to invoke a Cloud Function from Cloud Function with a JSON Body.

only a example code

```
// Cloud Function URL
url := "https://[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION_NAME]"

// Request body
requestBody := []byte(`{"name": "John"}`)

// Create HTTP client
client := &http.Client{}

// Create POST request with request body
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Send request and get response
response, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Print response body
var responseBody bytes.Buffer
_, err = responseBody.ReadFrom(response.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(responseBody.String())
```

but it failing with 401 unautorized The service Account of the cloud Function have Cloud Functions Invoker Role and access to the Cloud Function.

Comment: You didn't add the authorization header in your request, it can't work!

Comment: Your code does not include the HTTP Authorization header. Without that header, your code is making an anonymous request. Review the documentation and example code for Cloud Function Authorization.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the Authorization header

```golang
// Cloud Function URL
url := "https://[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION_NAME]"

// Request body
requestBody := []byte(`{"name": "John"}`)

// Create HTTP client with default service account credentials
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx, cloudfunctions.CloudPlatformScope)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Create POST request with request body
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Authenticate request using default service account credentials
token, err := google.DefaultTokenSource(ctx, cloudfunctions.CloudPlatformScope).Token()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
request.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+token.AccessToken)

// Send request and get response
response, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Print response body
var responseBody bytes.Buffer
_, err = responseBody.ReadFrom(response.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(responseBody.String())
```

Comment: Your code appears to request an OAuth Access Token. Cloud Functions require an OIDC Identity Token., which does not have an OAuth scope parameter but does require the endpoint URL.

Comment: @JohnHanley you right tried it with the bearer token allready and getting same issue